# How to change a variable in if condition of base class with super() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, inheritance

I have two classes with similar methods but there is a bit of difference in variables, here are the two classes:-

### First class

```py
class SerializerOne(object):

    def validate(self, data):
        instance = self.instance or self.Meta.model(**data)
        instance.full_clean()
        if data.get('certificate') and data.get('private_key'):
            data = get_import_data(instance)
        return data

    def validate_validity_start(self, value):
        if value is None:
            value = default_validity_start()
        return value

    def validate_validity_end(self, value):
        if value is None:
            value = default_ca_validity_end()
        return value
```

### Second class

```py
class SerializerTwo(object):

    def validate(self, data):
        instance = self.instance or self.Meta.model(**data)
        instance.full_clean()
        if data.get('certificate') and data.get('private_key'):
            data = get_import_data(instance)
            data.update({'ca': instance.ca})
        return data

    def validate_validity_start(self, value):
        if value is None:
            value = default_validity_start()
        return value

    def validate_validity_end(self, value):
        if value is None:
            value = default_cert_validity_end()
        return value
```

Now this is what I have tried to keep the similar methods in a base class:-

### Base class

```py
class BaseSerializer(object):
    def validate(self, data):
        instance = self.instance or self.Meta.model(**data)
        instance.full_clean()
        if data.get('certificate') and data.get('private_key'):
            data = get_import_data(instance)
        return data

    def validate_validity_start(self, value):
        if value is None:
            value = default_validity_start()
        return value

    def validate_validity_end(self, value):
        if value is None:
            value = default_ca_validity_end()
        return value
```

When I inherit the above `BaseSerializer`

```py
class SerializerOne(BaseSerializer):
    pass

class SerializerTwo(BaseSerializer):
    # Now in this class how can I add `data.update({'ca': instance.ca})` in the 
    # `validate` method, and also there is a bit of change in the 
    # method `validate_validity_end`,
```

I found that it can be done with `super()`, but I couldn't achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd redefine how you factor out the common methods a bit:

```
class BaseSerializer:
    def get_import_data_hook(self, instance):
        return get_import_data(instance)

    def validate(self, data):
        instance = self.instance or self.Meta.model(**data)
        instance.full_clean()
        if data.get('certificate') and data.get('private_key'):
            data = self.get_import_data_hook(instance)
        return data

    def default_validity_start_hook(self):
        return default_validity_start()

    def validate_validity_start(self, value):
        if value is None:
            value = default_validity_start_hook()
        return value

    def default_validity_end_hook(self):
        return default_ca_validity_end()

    def validate_validity_end(self, value):
        if value is None:
            value = self.default_validity_end_hook()
        return value
```

Any time you find yourself reusing all the code except a small tweak, put the tweak in its own hook. You don't have to put "hook" in the name, I just did that for emphasis. Instead, document it clearly.

Now you can do something like

```
class SerializerOne(BaseSerializer):
    pass
```

and

```
class SerializerTwo(BaseSerializer):
    def get_import_data_hook(self, instance):
        data = super().get_import_data_hook(instance)
        data.update({'ca': instance.ca})
        return data

    def default_validity_end_hook(self):
        return default_cert_validity_end()
```

Right now, making a separate hook for `default_validity_start_hook` seems superfluous, but I added it for consistency. You may also want to look into the functions `get_import_data`, `default_validity_start`, and `default_c*_validity_end` to see if they belong directly in your class structure. It would certainly make the part of the code you show a lot simpler.

Comment: Hi, default_validity_end_hook(self), in this method argument self is required. I guess, in both the classes, i.e., `BaseSerializer` and `SerializerTwo`.